# How do I launch a Tkinter (python) program from the desktop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Python3. I have a Tkinter program that works well from the IDLE shell. It is called TrackMyInvestments.py. I want to launch it from either the Terminal or better still from the Desktop so that I don't have the editor or shell each time.

If I go to the Terminal and to the directory where the program is located and then simply type in python3 TrackMyInvestments.py it opens and runs.

Next, I have included a shebang #!usr/bin/env TrackMyInvestments.py and then I have entered sudo chmod +x TrackMyInvestments at the terminal. When I then type in ./TrackMyInvestments.py I get the following:

```
bushbug@bushbug-Aspire-A315-53:~/TKinterFiles$ ./TrackMyInvestments.py
./TrackMyInvestments.py: line 4: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/tkinter
from: can't read /var/mail/tkcalendar
./TrackMyInvestments.py: line 8: import: command not found
./TrackMyInvestments.py: line 9: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/tkinter
./TrackMyInvestments.py: line 11: global: command not found
./TrackMyInvestments.py: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./TrackMyInvestments.py: line 14: `root=tk.Tk()'
```

I have also tried using an alias but receive the same error messages.

Finally I tried making a desktop "icon" to launch the program but when I click on it nothing happens.

I have watched a You Tube video by Codeworked and everything looks so simple yet none of the options work for me.

I have looked up as much information on the various problems as I can find. What can I try next?

Comment: The shebang line should be `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, is that what you have in the first line of your file?

Comment: To run py files is `python3 ./file.py`

Comment: Thank you for your reply Armadillan. Yes that exactly what I have.

Comment: Alex, that works. So does just python3 file.py. So, is there a difference between the two?

Comment: As your question stated *"I have included a shebang #!usr/bin/env TrackMyInvestments.py"*, so you don't put the required shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: I have created a Desktop "icon" containing the following:[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Investments
Version=1.0
Exec=/home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/TrackMyInvestments.py
Type=Application. This is supposed to call my program when I double click it. However, it only opens the editor. If I change the permissions  to "Excecute" it does nothing. Any suggestions regarding the above coding?

Comment: acw1668. Thank you for your comment. I have removed the shebang and when I type either ~/TKinterFiles$Pyhton3 TrackMyInvestments.py or ~/TKinterFiles$Python3 ./TrackMyInvestments.py the program executes. I would however like to find a way to get it to execute without having to open a terminal, ie. I would like to have an icon on the desktop containing code to launch the program.

Comment: Then it is nothing related to Python or tkinter.  It is just an issue on configuring desktop shortcut.

Comment: Oh, OK. I  apologise.